# OnDraw() method of Drawable class is not getting called

Tags: android, android-drawable, ondraw

I have tried everything possible available online, but this method is not called consistently. The onDraw() method is sometimes called and sometimes just neglected:
Please, please help me, any help is appreciated;
BadgeDrawable class: (want to draw a badge on to my notification icon in action bar)

```
public class BadgeDrawable extends Drawable {

private float mTextSize;
private Paint mBadgePaint;
private Paint mBadgePaint1;
private Paint mTextPaint;
private Rect mTxtRect = new Rect();

private String mCount = "";
private boolean mWillDraw = false;

public BadgeDrawable(Context context) {
    mTextSize = /*context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.badge_text_size)*/ 20;
    mBadgePaint = new Paint();
    mBadgePaint.setColor(ResourceReader.getInstance(context).getColorFromResource(R.color.colorPrimary));
    mBadgePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBadgePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mBadgePaint1 = new Paint();
    mBadgePaint1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));//white
    mBadgePaint1.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBadgePaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    mTextPaint = new Paint();
    mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
    //mTextPaint.setFlags(Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG);
    mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    this.setCallback(callback);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    Log.d("dj", "onDraw BadgeDrawable");
    if (!mWillDraw) {
        return;
    }

    Rect bounds = getBounds();
    float width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
    float height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
    float radius = ((Math.max(width, height) / 2)) / 2;
    float centerX = (width - radius - 1) +10;
    float centerY = radius -5;
    if(mCount.length() <= 2){
        // Draw badge circle.
        /*canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+9, mBadgePaint1);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+7, mBadgePaint);*/

        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+9, mBadgePaint1);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+7, mBadgePaint);
    }
    else{
        /*canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+10, mBadgePaint1);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+8, mBadgePaint);*/

        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+10, mBadgePaint1);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius+8, mBadgePaint);
    }
    // Draw badge count text inside the circle.
    mTextPaint.getTextBounds(mCount, 0, mCount.length(), mTxtRect);
    float textHeight = mTxtRect.bottom - mTxtRect.top;
    float textY = centerY + (textHeight / 2f);
    /*if(mCount.length() > 2)
    canvas.drawText("99+", centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
    else*/
    canvas.drawText(mCount, centerX, textY, mTextPaint);
}

/*
 Sets the count (i.e notifications) to display.
  */
public void setCount(String count) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "setCount count val- BadgeDrawable: "+count);
    mCount = count;
    // Only draw a badge if there are notifications.
    mWillDraw = !count.equalsIgnoreCase("0");
    invalidateSelf();
}


private Drawable.Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "invalidateDrawable - BadgeDrawable: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {

    }

    @Override
    public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {

    }
};

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.UNKNOWN;
}
```

}

So when I get the count of unread notification from server I set like this:

```
public static void setBadgeCount(Context context, LayerDrawable icon, String count) {

    BadgeDrawable badge; // Reuse drawable if possible
    Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge); //getting the layer 2
    if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
        badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
    } else {
        badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
    }
    badge.setCount(count);
    icon.mutate();
    icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
}
```

Comment: try setting the bounds of the drawable, does this solve the issue?

Comment: @Gil Moshayof I'm on it, thanks; BTW should i do this in the constructor ??

Comment: It depends - most the time you don't know what the bounds of your drawable is until a measure happens, u just need to make sure that the bounds are set, since if the width or height of the bounds are 0, the draw method won't be called.

Comment: @Gil Moshayof I am searching for whr to and how to set the bounds for a drawable (right way to do bounds). I'll get back ASAP and update :) and y does it call sometimes and not call other times (this is wierd and mysterious)

Comment: @Gil Moshayof your 100% right it does not call on draw if the bounds are 0; and mysteriously sometimes its 0 and sometimes its not; BTW the drawable wic i use host a drawable(background@drawable/my_icon) in xml; practically it must not be zero; is it fair enough for me to try and call setBounds before calling invalidateSelf() and set some dummy val, so it calls onDraw(); Please, please reply for this... thanks a lot for this valuable info

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the bounds of the drawable produce a width and height which is greater than 0. When a drawable's bound's width or height is 0, the `draw` method will not be called.

You can set the bounds of a drawable by calling `setBounds()` on the drawable itself.

**EDIT**

Another way to get a drawable to redraw itself is by using the level mechanism. This is good for drawables that animate, but can be used regardless.

You can trigger a refresh of the drawable by calling:

```
setLevel(getLevel() + 1)
```

In addition, if you want your drawable to redraw on a level change, you need to override the following method and return true:

```
@Override
protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {
    return true;
}
```

Perhaps you could even consider using the level instead of the "count" variable, as a redraw won't be triggered if the level did not change.

Hope this helps.

Comment: even If i set the bounds explicitly (callling setBounds()) in constructor, it still didnt call onDraw(); before calling invalidate, I checked the bounds it was showing the values what I set but still didnt call onDraw(); again suspicious :)

Comment: avoid calling invalidateSelf() on the drawable. Instead, call postInvalidate on the view that holds the drawable.

Comment: I dont have any views here (I am dealing with drawables only); i just retrieve a icon from menuitem, like: Drawable drw = menuItem.getIcon(); I manipulate on this icon. I cannot treat this drawable as a view;

Comment: Thanks again i'll check this out

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late. Answer is

```
public static void setBadgeCount(Context context, LayerDrawable icon, String count) {

BadgeDrawable badge; // Reuse drawable if possible
Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge); //getting the layer 2
if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
    badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
} else {
    badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
    icon.mutate();
    icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
}

badge.setCount(count);
```

}